# How to hide base href in angular 4 website hosted on S3

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a website hosted on a S3 bucket written in Angular 4.

I have the URL on Route 53 pointing to a CloudFront Distribution which points to the S3 Bucket's index.html (set to no cache).

In the S3 bucket I have folders for each version example:

```
mywebsite.com
-> v1.0.0
   -> pricing.html
-> index.html
```

In my index.html I have 
`<base href="/v1.0.0/">`

This works out perfect and goes to the correct pages and always gets the newest version of the website as index.html is not cached.

This however makes my url look like :
`https://www.mywebsite.com/v1.0.0/pricing`

How do I hide "/v1.0.0/" from the URL?

Comment: Note: I have the same exact setup on an angular 1 website and it doesn't add the version folder to the URL .... not sure why or how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay after many hours trying to figure this out I finally got it. Here's how I did it for anyone else trying to do this:

go into your **app.module.ts** file and add

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
```

Next, in the "providers" section add

```
  providers: [
[{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}]
],
```

Then when you upload the website edit index.html to have a base_href of the version folder:

```
<base href="/v1.0.9/">
```

Now it will pull all files from /v1.0.9/ folder but not display that in the URL!

Comment: For anyone else looking at this make sure you add the meta data with key "Cache-Control" value "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0" when uploading to AWS this will ensure your index doesn't ever gets cached, therefore always serving the newest version folder